# is there a way to delete last comma in each line and print table?

Tags: python-3.x

[multiplication table of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lerp4.png)

hi guys how can print this table(see picture) without last comma(,) in each line?
I already tried to move print() or delete (end=) but,
I can solve this problem

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
  for j in range(1, n+1):
      print(i*j, end=',')
  print()
```

Output (for input=6):

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,
2,4,6,8,10,12,
3,6,9,12,15,18,
4,8,12,16,20,24,
5,10,15,20,25,30,
6,12,18,24,30,36,
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures copy and paste your code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place a condition on the value of `end`, to use a comma when it's not the last element.

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
  for j in range(1, n+1):
      print(i*j, end=',' if j<n else '')
  print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you can do this by list comprehension. Take a look at the example:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(*[i*j for j in range(1, n +1)], sep=', ')
```